# Electomagnetism in curved spacetime

Tags: electromagnetism, general-relativity, lagrangian-formalism

I solved the exercise 1 sec. 4.9 of Carroll book and I would like to understand what|s the physics behind the result.
I was asked to find the energy momentum tensor of the Lagrangian:

\begin{equation}
    \sqrt{-g}\hat{\mathcal{L}}=\mathcal{L}=\sqrt{-g} \left(-\frac{1}{4} F^{\mu \nu}F_{\mu \nu} + A_{\mu} J^{\mu} \right) 
\end{equation}
and I found the result (I believe is correct):

\begin{equation}
    T_{\alpha \beta}= g_{\alpha \beta} \hat{\mathcal{L}}+ F_{\mu \alpha}F^{\mu }_{\beta} + \frac{1}{2}(A_{\alpha} J_{\beta}+A_{\beta} J_{\alpha})
\end{equation}
The second part of the question is the one I am more confused about. We add to the lagrangian a new term

\begin{equation}
    \mathcal{L}_1=\beta R^{\mu \nu }g^{\rho \sigma} F_{\mu \rho} F_{  \nu \sigma }
\end{equation}
but i guess is should be

\begin{equation}
    \mathcal{L}_1= \sqrt{-g} \beta R^{\mu \nu }g^{\rho \sigma} F_{\mu \rho} F_{  \nu \sigma } \quad (1)
\end{equation}
I went on using equation $(1)$ and I found that the Maxwell equations are not modified but this term while Einstein equations are:

\begin{equation}
    R_{\alpha\beta}- \frac{1}{2} g_{\alpha\beta} R + \beta R^{\mu \nu} F_{\nu\beta}F_{\alpha\mu} = T_{\alpha\beta}
\end{equation}
I would like to ask a physical interpretation of the result. Is there a reason we are adding $(1) $ to the Lagrangian? Is this a new theory of gravity in this case? Is this case interesting in some application?

Comment: I would just comment that the common perspective is: any term which can be added to the Lagrangian, should be so long as it obeys the symmetries we are interested in. The order in which we add new terms then goes by lowest order (smallest number of fields in the product) to highest. So in principle, we would also add terms like $\sqrt{-g}R^2$ too, but this will be higher order in $g$ than just $\sqrt{-g}R$.